# Loading data into Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Okay, so lets say I have an api, which returns a object of data in json. The object looks like the following.

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name":"SynAck",
    "sex":"Male",
    "age":34,
    "roles": [
        {
            "id":1
            "name":"user"
            "assigned":"2013-06-10"
        },
        {
            "id":1
            "name":"admin"
            "assigned":"2014-01-09"
        }
    ],
    "created":"2014-06-10"
}
```

As you can see there are 2 objects returned here namely, the first one, lets call it "user" and another object, which is an array inside the first, "roles". There are 2 roles assigned to the user.

So lets say I want to load this information up into my DB verbatim. I could create 3 tables, 'user' and 'roles' and 'user_roles', with foreign keys linking user->user_roles->roles. One user has many roles.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id`      INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `sex`     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `age`     SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
  `id`          INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `assigned`    DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_roles` (
  `user_id`     INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `role_id`     INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ur_user_id` FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ur_role_id` FOREIGN KEY(`role_id`) REFERENCES roles(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE `idx_user_id_role_id`(`user_id`, `role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

I would then use artisan to create the Eloquent models and in the user model, I would have a `hasManyThrough('roles', 'user_roles');`

What would be the quickest and cleanest way of loading the data from the json into the models/tables?

Would I just have to assign the values one by one, or is there a way to map the attributes from the json objects to the eloquent model? If this is possible, how does it handle the relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is possible to create the models for each table and then use the funcion `json_decode` to convert the JSON to an array and then use Eloquent methods to save then. Raw example:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
User::create($data);
```

Still, you need to extract the relationship data. Raw example:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$roles = $data['roles'];
unset($data['roles']);

$user = User::create($data);
$user->roles()->create($roles);
```

Comment: Would `$user->roles()->create($roles);` create the entries in the `users_roles` table?

Comment: Yes, it would. More information http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models